# NSManagedObjectContext's propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent set to false causes error on save

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a pair of Core Data Entities of One-to-Many relationship.

```
Department <-(optional) (delete rule: Cascade) (optional)->> Item

Item <-(optional) (delete rule: Nullify) (optional)->> Department
```

`Item` is a tree node-like entity, which also has a relationship to itself. The tree can grow quite large (more than 10 thousands nodes in a root branch).

There are a parent background `NSManagedObjectContext` and a main-queue one as the child.

In the hope of making deletion of `Items` feel faster, I set the main-queue MOC's [`propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506228-propagatesdeletesatendofevent) to `false`. (The change will be saved when the app Resigns Active. ) Unfortunately there will be error messages when the main-queue MOC is saved:

> validation recovery attempt FAILED with Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1600 ...

If `propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent` is the default `true`, there's no error.

My deletion code looks like this, nothing special:

```
department.removeFromItems(items as NSSet) // Optional. Also tried without this line.
for i in items {
    self.managedObjectContext!.delete(i)
}
```

I see very few talks about the usage of `propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent`. Any examples or explainations of the error will be appreciated.

Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172491/how-to-correctly-propagate-delete-from-main-threads-nsmanagedobjectcontext-to-c). But it has nothing to do with the `propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent` property.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581569/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-delete-a-large-number-10-000-objects-in-cor) about deleting large number of objects.

Comment: I am convinced that setting propagatesDeletesAtEndOfEvent flag to false and performing operations on the context breaks some underlying assumptions of the library, I cannot get it to work with any relationship in the model.

Comment: Another question that tries to explain what it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022200/what-does-setpropagatesdeletesatendofevent-actually-do